# Picture.pbm --> decimal, in c++

Tags: c++

just want to ask if anyone knows why I cant convert an entire picture into decimal.

Problem: after about 180 couts it turns 0 for the rest of the pixels.

Code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    char unsigned charTemp = 0;
    int unsigned intTemp = 0;

    std::fstream file;
    file.open("PIC.pbm", std::ios::in);

    //Ignore header
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    file.ignore();
    }

    //read and print
    //img res is 40x40 = 1600
    for (int i = 0; i < 1600; i++) {
        file >> charTemp;
        intTemp = charTemp;
        std::cout << intTemp << " ";
        charTemp = 0;
        intTemp = 0;
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Pic: any 40x40 pbm

Comment: You mean you want a decimal textual representation of each byte that makes up the file?

Comment: Do you really want 1600 decimal integers on one line?

Comment: Just what "decimal" would a 40x40 ppm be converted to?

Comment: A common view is to use hexadecimal.  Pixel channels are easier to view in hexadecimal.

Comment: You should check `fstream::good` after each `>>` operation. I'm guessing you've got a read error somewhere.

Comment: You may need to access the header elements to determine the bits or bytes per pixel and the number of channels, e.g. red, green, blue, alpha, etc.

Comment: If you want to read 8-bit quantities, you should use `uint8_t`.

Comment: @ScottHunter Its a greyscale and i would like to print out the pixels gray value (0-255) in decimal

Comment: Big issue:  you need to open the file in `binary` mode, so that no translations occur (for example, converting 0x0A to 0x0D0A or ending the file at 0x1A).

Comment: Also, the picture file is most likely not in text format.  You'll need to use `fstream::read()` instead of the extraction operator >>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better method with picture and image files is to read them as `binary` files:

```
std::ifstream file("PIC.pbm", ios::binary);
std::vector<unsigned char> bitmap(1600);

// Skip over the header
file.seekg(13, ios::beg); // Skip over 13 bytes.

// Read in the data at once
file.read((char *) &bitmap[0], 1600);

// Now process the bitmap from memory
for (int i = 0; i < 1600; ++i)
{
  cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(bitmap[i]) << " ";
  if ((i % 40) == 39)
  {
    cout << "\n";
  }
}
cout << "\n";
```

The idea here is to read in the bitmap in one transaction into memory.  Streams like to flow (don't interrupt the flow).  Memory is faster to access than files, so the bitmap values are processed from memory.

The cast is used so that the formatted insertion doesn't treat the byte as a character, but a number.

Comment: Tank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

First, open your `PIC.pbm` file in another hex editor because it's quite possible that those bytes really are zeroes. If not, then you've got problems reading the file.

The `fstream` constructor does not default to reading in binary mode, so it reads files as "text" - and I've learned the hard way that you can't trust the standard-library with knowing anything about text anymore (what with mishandling Unicode, line-endings, etc - I feel it's best to always use `binary` and a dedicated Unicode library).

You should check the `fstream::good()` function after each read operation to see if it failed, and if so, then check `iostate`:

```
using namespace std;

// ...

fstream file;
file.open( "PIC.pbm", ios::in | ios::binary );
file.ignore( 13 );

for (int i = 0; i < 1600; i++) {

    file >> charTemp;
    if( !file.good() ) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Error reading file: iostate == " << file.iostate << endl;
        break;
    }
    else {
        intTemp = charTemp;
        std::cout << intTemp << " ";
        charTemp = 0;
        intTemp = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe an issue is that the file needs to be open in `binary` mode and to use `read()` rather than using the extraction operator.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Good point, thank you. I've amended my answer.